# For how many seconds do I need to turn the pedal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

For how many seconds do I need to turn the pedal of a bike, so that the number of turns is equal to the value of my velocity in the given moment measured in km/h.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're starting from rest, $0$ does the job--and I don't think there is enough information given to determine any other answers.

Comment: I thought the same, but 0 is too simple for a problem from a math competition.

Comment: Well, without more information, like gear ratios, there's nothing more we can do, so far as I can tell.